# How to deal with many stateless servers and race condition of insert vs. update in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We have many records coming in (denormalized) such that

- Bob Smith addr1
- Bob Smith addr2
- Joe Turn addr1

We get lots of exceptions when both servers try to check if Bob Smith exists and then both try to insert the same record.  We are fine with either LAST write wins OR first write wins.  Instead, an exception is thrown since there is already a record.

What solutions have people used to solve this issue?  We know of one with MySQL and hibernate and the @SQLInsert but as we add columns, the annotation does not get updated leading to issues over time (ie. it's not very ideal).  If we could just do @SQLInsert with no query or something like that, that would be the most ideal.

Any ideas for solving this issue?

(Personally, I am wishing this was in noSQL right now, but that's a hard pivot)

The situation above occurs when

- server 1 reads there is no Bob Smith yet
- server 2 reads there is no Bob Smith yet
- server 1 mgr.flush, and tx.commit results in insert success
- server 2 mgr.flush, and tx.commit results in insert failure

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Preferably with examples of what server one and server two try to store, and why it is currently failing. If you mean that you don't care whether 'Bob Smith addr1' or 'Bob Smith addr2' ultimately gets stored, then (at least from your description alone) I can't really understand why a simple `session.merge()` isn't the solution

Comment: @crizzis I edited the post on exactly how this occurs.  basically server 2 fails as it thinks it needs to insert when it needs to update and there is no way for it to know(after all, it's a race condition).

Comment: If you're fine with 'first write wins', why is the exception in the other transaction an issue? Sorry, but I don't think there's a scenario in which both transactions succeed that doesn't use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (which I'm assuming is your current solution)